# Mingw C++ Building Dynamic/Static x86/x64

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, gnu-make

So I'm on Windows, and I'm wondering how to build a DLL and a Static Library in MingW, and in different architectures like x86 and x64. I'm new to MingW, but not C++. I've been looking around Google a while and haven't found a way to do it yet, the reason being is because most of the tutorials I find are out-of-date.

**GNU 'Make' File**

```
Sources = Test.cpp Utilities.cpp
Objects = $(Sources:.cpp=.o)

ProjName = MyProgram
BuildName = $(ProjName).dll

$(ProjName) : $(Objects)
    g++ -o $(BuildName) $(Objects)

$(Objects) :
    g++ -c -D TEST_DYNAMIC $(Sources)

Clean :
    rm $(Objects) $(BuildName)
```

**Addition Information**

Mingw Version: 4.8.1-4

**Attempts**

```
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll

-shared is an unrecognized command.
```

Comment: What version of mingw are you using?

Comment: Mingw Version: 4.8.1-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out why it wasn't working. Those sites are not out-of-date, my MingW was, but my system was using Cygwin, which is what I don't want. So I changed my 'Path' variable to direct it to the correct Mingw.